# CSS multiple Background Images both repeat-x

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-repeat

I try to get multiple background images in one div at the moment. **Both** must repeat-x.

The **first image** should start at the **top-left point up to 50%** of the div.

The second should start at the **middle to the right end** of the div.

I tried the following:

```
.myDiv {
    background-image: url('image1.png'), url('image2.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
    background-position: left top, center top;
    background-size: 50% 100%, 50% 100%;
}
```

My problem is that only image1 is shown.

Comment: The `repeat-x` up to `50%` will be an issue, as you can't have a conditional end point (at least with CSS 2.1). It will just continue repeating horizontally. Unfortunately, you would need to get hacky with overlaying elements to achieve this.

Comment: @JackPattishall ok thank you for the clarification :( so lets play with two divs then....

Answer (score 0):

Try with that `background: url('image1.png'), url('image2.png');` instead of `background-image:`

Here is a [demo in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ojuwk6n3/)

You can see both images appear.

Hope it hepls

Comment: same result as my try

Comment: thx for the fiddle tried to make one myself... but my goal is that one image is starting left until the center and the second is starting in the center until the right border

Comment: I don’t know is this can be achieved only with one div background. Repeat is for the axis you choose to repeat. You can't stop where you want (if I’m correct). You can try making one container div, then other 2 inside with one image as bg in each div an place de divs where you want. Here is an example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mwc2n95t/)

Answer (score 0):

Set two background images for the any element like this

```css
background: 
   url(number.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,  /* On top,    like z-index: 4; */
   url(thingy.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,   /*            like z-index: 3; */
   url(Paper-4.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Devilquest. I was having issues with "top repeat-x , bottom repeat-x" for 2 images in one div. Works on Chrome, fails on IOS. Swapped to

```
 background: url ();
 background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
 background-position: top , bottom;
```

and now working fine on safari, iPhones etc