# html image auto adjust size of div

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, phpmyadmin

[image: Example]

The number of checkboxes can extend to like 40. If that happends, the scroll bar works and you can scroll to the right.
But i want that the image also adjust itself to that length. 
So right now if i scroll to the right the image automatically stops.

Also when there are only 2 checkboxes, i want the train to be that smal. (So i just want the image to adjust to the length of the checkboxes.

The code is:

```
<div id="axle_bogie_border">
    <!--This is the train image-->
            <img src="Images/axle_train.png" alt="train">
        <!--The show axles are the number of checkboxes (Filled in by a user)-->
        <div id="show_axles">
            <?php  
                $_POST['number_of_axles'];
                    if(isset($_POST['number_of_axles'])){
                    for($i=0; $i<$_POST['number_of_axles']; $i++){
                        echo "Axle " . "$i " . "<input type='checkbox' name='axles[$i]'>";
                    }   
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#axle_bogie_border {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 98%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}

#axle_bogie_border img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The show axles div has no content yet.

This is a example of how it looks now:

[image: Website example now]

And as you can see the train does not continue after a certain length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should slice the train image into an engine and a carriage image and then define the carriage-image as background-image of #axle_bogie_border with background-repeat:repeat-x.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Maybe this is helpful: [CSS multiple Background Images both repeat-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840116/css-multiple-background-images-both-repeat-x)

Comment: Il take a look at it! :)